# Probability and statistics(Properties of Discrete random variables)

Tags: probability

Let $T$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. Let $X$ be a discrete random variable defined as $X=k$ if $k\underline{<}$ $T<k+1,k=0,1....$ Find the frequency function of $X$

What i tried

The only part of this question which i do not understand is that why can we integrate the variable when it is discrete. Could anyone explain, Thanks

Comment: $P(k \le T < k+1 ) = \int_k^{k+1} \varphi(x) \textrm{d}x$ with $\varphi(x)$ the probability density.

Comment: You should not say $T=e^\lambda$.  You might say $P(T \le x)= e^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: The only part of this question which i do not understand is that why can we integrate the variable when it is discrete. Could u explain, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of $T \sim Exp(rate = \lambda)$ is 
$F_T(t) = P(T \le t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t},\;$ for $t > 0.$
Then 
$$P(X = k) = P(k \le T < k+1) = 1-e^{-(k+1)\lambda} -[1- e^{-k\lambda}] = e^{-k\lambda}-e^{-(k+1)\lambda},$$
for $k = 0, 1, \dots .$

For example, if $\lambda = 1,$ we have the following computations and simulations from R:

```
# Computation of exact values, rounded to 6 places
lam = 1;  N = 15;  prob1 = prob2 = numeric(N+1)
for (j in 1:(N+1)) {
  prob1[j] = exp(-lam*(j-1)) - exp(-lam*j)  # equation above
  prob2[j] = diff(pexp(c(j-1, j), lam))  }  # diff of CDF values
k = 0:N;  round(cbind(k, prob1, prob2), 6)
       k    prob1    prob2
 [1,]  0 0.632121 0.632121
 [2,]  1 0.232544 0.232544
 [3,]  2 0.085548 0.085548
 [4,]  3 0.031471 0.031471
 [5,]  4 0.011578 0.011578
 [6,]  5 0.004259 0.004259
 [7,]  6 0.001567 0.001567
 [8,]  7 0.000576 0.000576
 [9,]  8 0.000212 0.000212
[10,]  9 0.000078 0.000078
[11,] 10 0.000029 0.000029
[12,] 11 0.000011 0.000011
[13,] 12 0.000004 0.000004
[14,] 13 0.000001 0.000001
[15,] 14 0.000001 0.000001
[16,] 15 0.000000 0.000000
sum(prob1 * k)
[1] 0.5819748  # good approx of E(X) from 16 terms
```

---

```
# Simulation using 'floor' function
m = 10^6;  lam = 1
t = rexp(m, lam);  x = floor(t)
round(table(x)/m, 4)  # rounded to 4 places; mostly accurate to 3
x
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
0.6321 0.2323 0.0858 0.0315 0.0118 0.0042 0.0016 0.0005 
     8      9     10     11     12     13 
0.0002 0.0001 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
mean(t); mean(x)
[1] 1.000104  # sim value of E(T)
[1] 0.581973  # sim value of E(X)
```

The graph below shows the relationship between simulated integer values of $X$
(histogram bars centered on integers) and the density function of $T \sim Exp(1).$
Values of $X > 7,$ too infrequent to show on the histogram,
have been omitted.

[image]

Comment: The only part of this question which i do not understand is that why can we integrate the variable when it is discrete. Could u explain, Thanks

Comment: The discrete random variable $X$ 'inherits' its properties from the continuous exponential distribution of $T.$ We need to integrate the continuous distribution to find the probability function of $X.$ But once I have the PDF of $X,$ no more integration. Practical application: lifetime of a device is exponentially distributed with $\lambda=1.$ We look at the end of every week to see if it is still 'alive'. If dead at time $k$ we record that it lived until $k−1.$ Mean lifetime of $X$ is shown in computations $E(X)≈\sum_{k=0}^{15}kP(X=k)=.582$ ('most' of an infinite sum, NOT an integral).